# How to choose right Haskell C type?

Tags: c, haskell, types, ffi

I have studied some Haskell programming language and now I found out that it's possible to call Haskell functions from C programs. During my Haskell studies, I created a word frequency counter with Haskell and I would like to try to call that function from a C program, but I don't know how to do it. I found these two websites on haskell.org:

[Calling Haskell from C](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C)

[Foreign C types (Haskell module)](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Foreign-C-Types.html)

Despite that, I'm a bit lost which types to use. My haskell programs is a pipeline of following functions:

> putStr . unlines . map testF . sortedTree

where my own functions

- **testF** is type of **testF :: Show a => ([Char],a) -> [Char]**
- **sortedTree** is type of **sortedTree :: (Num a, Ord a) => [Char] -> [([Char],a)]**

I'm quite sure that I need to convert the types of each function to C types, instead of converting just the function that calls the pipeline. The type of the "main" function is

**fileFreq :: [Char] -> IO ()**

Besides all this, I'm using a Haskell binary tree, that isn't prelude type.

Here is the whole Haskell code:

```
module WordCounter where

import List
import Char
import Foreign.C.Types

data BTree a = Tip | BNode a (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving Show

insertFreq x Tip = BNode (x,1) Tip Tip
insertFreq x (BNode (q,p) l r)  | (map toLower x)==(map toLower q)  = BNode (q, p+1) l r
                | otherwise                 = BNode (q,p) l (insertFreq x r)

tlist :: BTree a -> [a]
tlist Tip = []
tlist (BNode x l r) = concat [tlist l, [x], tlist r]

sortedTree x = sortBy (\(x,y) (p,q) -> compare q y) (tlist (foldr insertFreq Tip (words x)))

testF (x, n) = concat (x : ":" : " \t\t\t " : show n : [])

concord = putStr . unlines . map testF . sortedTree

fileFreq filename = do { text <- readFile filename; concord text }
```

Can anyone guide me a bit with this?

Comment: Cool question, unfortunately  nobody on this matrix seems to be helpful http://asset.soup.io/asset/0750/2820_15d5_960.jpeg I hope it is not offending, just amusing while you wait for a reasonable answer. +1 of course

Comment: This is unclear to me.  Could you be explicit about which Haskell function you wish to call from C?  Pretend you have the bindings working - what does a simple C caller look like?

Comment: @TomMD: I'm trying to call the fileFreq function from a C program. Simple C caller would look like just a simple C program that has only the Haskell function call in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you will need to do is to create wrapper functions for the functions you need exposed to C and there do the work of converting from C-types to haskell types.

You will also need to enable the ForeignFunctionInterface extension, also any exceptions that may occur in the haskell code need to be handled in the wrapper functions.

For example, if you only need to expose your top-level function fileFreq to C you could add a function like:

```
fileFreq_hs :: CString -> IO CInt
fileFreq_hs cstr = catch (wrap_fileFreq cstr) (\_ -> return (-1))
  where wrap_fileFreq = do
          str <- peekCString cstr
          fileFreq str
          return 0
```

to create a function that marshals a C-string into a haskell string (using functions from Foreign.C.String), calls your fileFreq function and translates exceptions to C error codes (-1 if exception happened, 0 otherwise).

Then you need to export it using

```
foreign export ccall fileFreq_hs :: CString -> IO CInt
```

and of course you need to add:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
```

at the top of your module.

Then you can follow the instructions in the links you provided to compile this to a C-stub and header file and create a C-file that you can compile with ghc.

It is of course possible to wrap any function you have, you just need to make sure to handle possible exceptions and to marshal between C-types and haskell types.

The complete code with my modifications is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module WordCounter where

import List
import Char
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.C.String
import Control.Monad

data BTree a = Tip | BNode a (BTree a) (BTree a) deriving Show

insertFreq x Tip = BNode (x,1) Tip Tip
insertFreq x (BNode (q,p) l r)  | (map toLower x)==(map toLower q)  = BNode (q, p+1) l r
                | otherwise                 = BNode (q,p) l (insertFreq x r)

tlist :: BTree a -> [a]
tlist Tip = []
tlist (BNode x l r) = concat [tlist l, [x], tlist r]

sortedTree :: (Ord t, Num t) => String -> [([Char], t)]
sortedTree x = sortBy (\(x,y) (p,q) -> compare q y) (tlist (foldr insertFreq Tip (words x)))

testF :: (Show t) => ([Char], t) -> [Char]
testF (x, n) = concat (x : ":" : " \t\t\t " : show n : [])

concord = putStr . unlines . map testF . sortedTree

fileFreq filename = do { text <- readFile filename; concord text }

fileFreq_hs :: CString -> IO CInt
fileFreq_hs cstr = catch (wrap_fileFreq cstr) (\_ -> return (-1))
  where wrap_fileFreq cstr = do
          str <- peekCString cstr
          fileFreq str
          return 0
foreign export ccall fileFreq_hs :: CString -> IO CInt
```

Comment: I tried your code and I can compile it with no errors. However there is are at least two things that I'm wondering:

 a) Why only the called fileFreq function needs to be "converted"? Does the GHC compiler automatically handle the subfunction types?

 b) I tried to understand the very weird looking _stub.c source file and unfortunately I have no idea how I should input the text file that I would like to process. The definiton of the fileFreq function in the .c file is "HsInt32 fileFreq_hs(HsPtr a1)".

Comment: The only place where you need to worry about types is the functions that you want exported to C-code. There and only there you need to convert between C-types and Haskell types. The subfunction types don't need to be modified, and indeed shouldn't be modified. The GHC compiler will not do anything about the subfunction types, rather you explicitely convert to haskell types, then all other functions use Haskell types. As a C-user you only need to include the generated header file, and then compile all files together with your C file using GHC (as per the link you had in your question).

Comment: Thanks. I think all this is slowly starting to make sense :)